# References in C

Tags: c, reference

This is a theoretical question.

I wonder how certain constructions in C are performed internally without references. For example:

```
struct Foo { int a; };
int main() {
  struct Foo foo;
  foo.a = 10;
  return 0;
}
```

What is the type of `foo.a`? It's definitely not a pointer, because we assign `10` as a value, not address. But it's not a value type as well, because it changes data of `foo`. In C++ I would just say that it's a reference, but in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an int lvalue. Same as if you had `int bar`, and `bar = 10` changes the data of `bar`. Same applies to any element within an array. Basically anything you can take the address of is an lvalue.

Lvalue status is independent of type.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason a reference is "needed" here in C++ is operator overloading. In C, the `=` sign is not a function call that needs a reference argument. It's simply an operator. It can't be redefined and made to do nonsensical stuff, so a normal lvalue is perfectly fine for it.

Note that there's no fundamental reason C++ needed references for this either. It could just as well have specified the overloaded `operator=` etc. functions to receive pointers rather than references.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `foo.a` is `int`. Think about it this way: writing `foo.a = 5` is the same as writing `*((int*)(&foo + offset_of_a)) = 5` - it's just writing data to a certain memory location which is to be interpreted a a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in c are really just big primitives. if you look at the assembler generated for your foo assignment, it just acts like an int.  Here's an example:

I have my struct definition:

```
 typedef struct Foo Foo;
 struct Foo {
     int a, b;
 };
```

And I declare a Foo:

```
 Foo foo = {0,1};
```

The stack (a little machine-specific stuff is being glossed over, but in general) looks like this (assuming 4-bit ints and one-bit bytes)

```
%esp  %ebp[-8]  %ebp[-4]  %ebp
[....   0000      0001    ....]
```

you find that the instruction to assign `foo.b = 1` is

```
mov $1, -4(%ebp)
```

Which is the same instruction that would assign an `int` on the stack a value.

Comment: I've never seen a 'one-bit byte' before.